# Draw boxes around nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to create something like this:
[image]

from the following code without the boxes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%layout
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
\node[main] (1) {$C$}; 
\node[main] (2) [right of=1] {A}; 
\node[main] (3) [below right of=2] {B}; 
\node[main] (4) [above right of=2] {$\neg$B}; 
\node[main] (5) [below right of=4] {$\neg$A}; 
\node[main] (6) [right of=5] {$\neg$C};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) to [bend right=30] (3);
\draw[->] (2) -- (4);
\draw[->] (3) to [bend right=30](2);
\draw[->] (3) -- (5);
\draw[->] (4) to [bend right=30] (5);
\draw[->] (5) to [bend right=30] (4);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `fit` library and also don't forget to use `rotate fit` command to allow the non horizontal fitting. I also changed a bit your main nodes description to let you have all nodes the same size.

[image: draw boxes around nodes with fit]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%layout
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                node distance={20mm},
                thick,
                main/.style = {draw, circle, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=8mm},
                box/.style = {draw,red,inner sep=10pt,rounded corners=5pt}] 
                
                \node[main] (1) {$C$}; 
                \node[main] (2) [right of=1] {A}; 
                \node[main] (3) [below right of=2] {B}; 
                \node[main] (4) [above right of=2] {$\neg$B}; 
                \node[main] (5) [below right of=4] {$\neg$A}; 
                \node[main] (6) [right of=5] {$\neg$C};
                \draw[->] (1) -- (2);
                \draw[->] (2) to [bend right=30] (3);
                \draw[->] (2) -- (4);
                \draw[->] (3) to [bend right=30](2);
                \draw[->] (3) -- (5);
                \draw[->] (4) to [bend right=30] (5);
                \draw[->] (5) to [bend right=30] (4);
                \draw[->] (5) -- (6);
            
                \node[box,fit=(1)] {};
                \node[box,rotate fit=45,fit=(2)(3)] {};
                \node[box,rotate fit=45,fit=(4)(5)] {};
                \node[box,fit=(6)] {};
            \end{tikzpicture} 
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

A quick edit to let you know that, since here the angle between the two nodes containing `A` and `B` is 45 degrees, there's no need to compute anything. But if in the future, you want to do the same between two nodes that are not so simply put, you'll have to compute the angle before, like this:

```
\pgfextractangle{\angle}{2}{3}
\node[box,rotate fit=\angle,fit=(2)(3)] {};
```

where `\pgfextractangle` is defined like the following:

```
\newcommand{\pgfextractangle}[3]{%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
                              {\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}
    \global\let#1\pgfmathresult  
}
```

Comment: Nice, I discovered (¡now!) the `rotate fit`. But I can't find where `\pgfextractangle` is defined... Isn't `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` the command to use?

Comment: I normally use `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{b}{center}}\edef\aaa{\pgfmathresult}` to find the angle between two node centers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the definition of my `pgfextractangle` command, I edited my answer...